# Django - models design issue

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I'm struggling designing my models on Django (using PostgreSQL).

The goal is to create a system of groups where a user can arrange items in them. An item must be unique in my database. However I don't want items to be in groups in my database. I want a list of items that belong to a user and that can be sorted in groups.

A user owns objects. He can then sort them into groups. But he doesn't need to do so.

I created a user item group (`UserItemGroup`) that belong to a user (`User`). Then, I created an item model (`UserItem`). This model represents an item which the user can arrange into groups. Items can belong to multiple groups at the same time but must be unique! I used 2 `ForeignKey` in the `UserItem` model but it seems very weird... See below:

```
class UserItemGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)

class UserItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserItemGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Items can be arranged like so:

```
user_x
------group_a
------------item_1
------------item_2
------------item_3
------group_b
------------item_1
------------item_4
```

Hope I'm clear, thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think this design should be better :

```
class ItemGroup(models.Model):
    # Add next line only if you want to restrict Groups to user (if they are not shared)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class UserItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(UserItemGroup, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then you can display user's items like so :

```
# Get all possible groups from the user items
for group in ItemGroup.objects.filter(useritem__user=user).distinct():
    print(group.name)
    # Display all user items from this group
    print(user.useritem_set.filter(groups=group))
# Print items that are not in a group
print(user.useritem_set.filter(groups=None))
```

Comment: How do you define your useritem_set tho?

Comment: I just guess it because if the Model `UserItem` has a `ForeignKey` to user (without defining a `related_name`), then user should have an attribute `useritem_set` (cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the ForeignKey to `user` in your `UserItem` since an item is part of a group and a group depends on the user.

Also, you said an item can belong to multiple groups, so the relation must be a `ManyToManyField` :

```
class UserItem(models.Model):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(UserItemGroup, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

I've added a `name` field and set it as unique in order to ensure uniqueness on Item.
You can remove `the blank=True` from the `ManyToManyField` if an item have to be part of a group.

If you want to get all the items from a user, you can do :

```
UserItem.objects.filter(group__user=user).distinct()
```

Or sorted by group :

```
for group in user.useritemgroup_set.all():
    print(group.name)
    print(group.useritem_set.all())
```

Comment: I didn't downvoted this one. Though, it's a bit inconvenient because I need to request groups and the groups items to get all items that belong to a user right? This will also return me duplicates of items because they can be in multiple groups.

Comment: You can use .distinct() in your query to eliminate duplicates, this is proper database modeling

Comment: For me, items should be the primary thing to think of. Then we think of sorting items into groups, you know that I mean?

Comment: I don't want items to be in groups, I want them to be sorted in groups. While groups are tables that contain data too.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how you can query the objects with this design, which seems to be the most appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I'm ok with your answer however it seems a bit tricky to me: it's not very nice to retrieve all items like this. Also, how can I create an item without putting it in a group? 
I will try to be more clear: the user owns objects. He can then sort them into groups. But he is not obliged to do so.

Comment: Oh Ok I understand. As an item can possibly not be part of a group, how would we retrieve it from the user. I'm going to add a new answer